# Variable with kotlin for URL

Tags: variables, kotlin, var

I'm trying to complete an URL by means of variables but when I pass it and add it to the url I want to connect to, it gives me an error

```
    override fun onCreate
var mparam = intent.getStringExtra("param")


 interface ApiActaPartido {
             @GET("My_url"+$mparam)
             fun getActaPartido(): Call<ActaPartidoList>

        }
```

> Error:(84, 77) Expecting an element Error:(84, 14) An annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant

Help please.

Answer (score 2):

> An annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant

This is telling you that the compiler needs to know the value you are using in the annotation at compile time. Since you are getting that variable's value dynamically (`var mparam = intent.getStringExtra("param")`) it can't compile the value into the bytecode it's trying to build for you.

You will have to find a way to make the value used by `@GET` a compile-time constant, or use another method for doing whatever functionality it is intended to provide.

Comment: Java has the same requirement .

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass constants to annotation parameters. If `ConfigAmaters.DATA_ACTA` is not a constant then you cannot use it inside as an annotation parameter.

If it is actually a `val DATA_ACTA: String` that is inside an `object` then you can make it a constant by adding `const`:

```
object ConfigAmaters {
    const val DATA_ACTA: String = "..."
}
```

In this case the compiler shouldn't complain anymore.

Comment: yes, with this I can insert a string to the const val COD_INFO: String = "hello" but not the variable mparam